# NHibernate second level cache collection hydration takes too long

Tags: performance, optimization, query-cache, nhibernate, query-performance

I have enabled query caching and entity caching in NHibernate to store large collections of objects, needed for repetitive operations. While I have minimized the number of hits to db, the performance benefit is suboptimal.

Loading entities from second level cache takes way too long. Does anyone know how to optimize this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What cache provider are you using for second level cache? For example, If you're using memcached, this becomes a memcached question. If you're using syscache, it's a .NET question. Regardless, since the database is fast, but your cache is slow, you'll probably have better luck funding an answer on the main StackOverflow, rather than DBA.SE.

Comment: I'm using syscache. I'll post it on Stack Overflow, thank you for suggestion.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806599/nhibernate-second-level-cache-collection-hydration-takes-too-long